# Clip-path working in Chrome and Safari but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, clip-path

I've created an svg with d3 based on db data, which works fine. But when zooming-in the elements that have been drawn extend beyond the svg. I want to create a clippath to prevent this, which works in Chrome and Safari, but things get odd in Firefox:

The clip-path attribute is applied to child elements of a `<g>` (using a `url(#[id of <clippath>])` value).  When I use the Inspector in Firefox to manually apply the same clip-path attribute at this level, it appears to work fine, but for some reason it isn't reading it from my stylesheet. (Also, note that Firefox does recognize the attribute being applied to the elements in the stylesheet - it's not crossing it out or anything - it just doesn't seem to care!)

I can't use the overflow attribute instead, as I need this to be visible for other reasons.

My CSS:

```
#sectionID g.groupClass1 elements,
#sectionID g.groupClass2 elements,{
    clip-path: url(#clip);
}
```

My JS:

```
svgSelector.append("defs").append("clipPath")
.attr("id","clip")
.append("rect")
.attr("x", 0)
.attr("y", 0)
.attr("width", 500)
.attr("height", 500);
```

I've also tried without `<defs>`, which made no difference.

Any ideas?

I'll try to set up a fiddle as well in case it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I figured it out. I'm not sure why, but `clip-path` only seems to work as an element attribute (as compared to a style attribute) in Firefox - at least for my SVG elements.

I.e., it works when I change it from

```
<g style="clip-path:url(#clip)">
```

to something like

```
<g clip-path="url(#clip)">
```